# Preserve tabs in code

Tags: bug, code-formatting

Tabs are currently rendered as spaces in code blocks. I'm sure this is just a symptom of Markdown or an otherwise well-intentioned method to standardise code samples... However some code *needs* tabs to work.

Consider the `<<- EOF ... EOF` heredoc in Bash. The dash means it will skip a  number of leading tab characters. Not spaces. So [when you advertise this feature](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76483/880) (it makes code much more readable) and use it on the site, it breaks. The heredoc output is littered with leading spaces.

The example I used above is from Unix.SE. I believe this is as much an issue for them, just as it might be for any Bash-tagged question further afield.

Comment: I also had a issue with [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/140358/205792) on ServerFault - the makefile has spaces before `make -C` - a tab should be there instead, or else it gets a error about `Makefile:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.` when using the `make` command. N.B. In most browsers, trying to type 'Tab' ends up selecting the next input box - tabs are however converted to spaces even when copied in.